# multiprocessing.Pool cannot return OrderedDict subclass with additional argument

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to have a simple subclass of `OrderedDict` that gets created by a `Pool` then returned.

It seems that the pickling process when returning the created object to the pool tries to re-instantiate the object and fails due to the required additional argument in the `__init__` function.

This is a minimal (non) working example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from multiprocessing import Pool


class Obj1(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.x = x


def task(x):
    obj1 = Obj1(x)
    return obj1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(1) as pool:
        for x in pool.imap_unordered(task, (1,2,3)):
            print(x.x)
```

If I do this I get the following error.

> Exception in thread Thread-3:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 463, in _handle_results
>       task = get()
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
>       return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
>   TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Again this fails when the `task` functions returns to the pool and I guess the object gets pickled?

If I changed `OrderedDict` by a simple `dict` it works flawlessly....

I have a workaround to use `kwargs` and retrieve the attribute of interest but I am stumped about the error to start with. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()` methods for your class.

In those functions you can make sure that `x` is handled as well. For example:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    return self.x, self.items()

def __setstate__(self, state):
    self.x = state[0]
    self.update(state[1])
```

BTW, from CPython 3.6 there is no reason to use `OrderedDict`, since dictionary order is insertion order. This was originally an implementation detail in CPython. In Python 3.7 it was made part of the language.

Comment: Interesting about __getstate__ and __setstate__. Could you elaborate on how to do it?  As for the dict keeping the order I’m happy to see it is finally part of the language! I remember 3.6 saying we shouldn’t rely on it. It makes things much simpler.